# Merge [magic-quotes-gpc] into [magic-quotes]

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

[magic-quotes-gpc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magic-quotes-gpc) [magic-quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magic-quotes)

They are the same thing.

Comment: They are *not* the same thing, but it's entirely safe to merge them nevertheless.